# ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMI, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install some libraries in my vscode:

selenium
webdriver-manager
key
By
Options
os-win
requests
openai
PySimpleGUI

But when i use the command pip install -r bibliotecas.txt with the archive opened, this error shows up:

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMI
Running setup.py clean for PyMI
Failed to build PyMI
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMI, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Can someone help? what can i do to install those libraries?

I tried:

pip install --upgrade pip (but the pip was already upgraded)
pip cache clean (but keeps giving the error in installation)
installed windowsSDK (bc ive seen in another forum that would work, but still the same error)

Comment: And you have Visual Studio installed ? https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: PS. The actual error is not present in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your complete error message.